# My for loop is not returning the desired plot [pinescript]

Tags: for-loop, pine-script

I'm trying to make an average open interest indicator based on the past number of years inputted (the input is called lookback), but am not understanding the for loop.  The plot will return a cumulative number forever increasing.
I've tried fiddling a few things.  I know the script is reading the for loop of because if I just do plot(openint[i]) I can toggle the input and it gives me the open interest from the amount of bars back I specify.  But my code doesn't accumulate a total number of open interest using the for loop.

Any idea what i'm doing wrong? This is a clip of the code i'm having trouble with below

```html
openint   = security("QUANDL:CFTC/"+code+"|0", "D", close) 
 
var float totaloi = 0
y = 0.0
var float xx = 0
z = for i = 0 to ((lookback)*52) by 52
    totaloi := nz(totaloi) + openint[i]
    y := y + totaloi
    
total = y/lookback

plot(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to run this on the weekly chart and it will only give you the average for the current week we're in.

```
years = input(3)

oi = security("QUANDL:CFTC/" + code + "|0", "W", close)

float oi_sum = 0.0

for i = 0 to years * 52 by 52
    oi_sum += oi[i]

oi_avg = oi_sum / years

plot(oi_avg)
```

Comment: Hi
Thanks for the reply. It was my fault describing what I was trying.  I was trying to call the open interest at the same time one year backwards.  So I could make an average for that week in the year.

Comment: Ok, i get you now, I've updated the answer.